# How to convert array of strings to bytebuffer type?

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

I have a String array which i would like to convert to ByteBuffer type. I am using this code right now but i am not sure if its the correct way to do it. 
   `ByteBuffer.wrap(values.toString().getBytes())`

Please let me know if this is the right format i am doing. `values` is a string array here.

Thank you

Comment: I think you would want to loop over your values array and concat them using a StringBuilder in a format that suits you, depending on what your goal is.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to pass the entire array as bytebuffer parameter. I will try your suggestion. Thanks again

Comment: Your code will work but the strings will be in there in an odd format, it all depends on the format you want them to be in your buffer, and that is largly dependant on what you are trying to achieve with that buffer. Writing to a file? sending over the network,...

Comment: I will be writing the bytebuffer in to database.

Comment: `String[].toString()` will produce a `String` similar to `[Ljava.lang.String;@e48e1b`.  This is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, thats the reason i am not able to get the values printed. Right now, i am thinking of creating a bytebuffer array and then iterate through string array and add it to the bytebuffer array. Is it right way to do ?

Comment: @kich - how are you planning to write the buffer to a database? If you're writing to a CLOB, then there are easier ways to do it.

Comment: Also, if you just dump your strings into a bytebuffer, you'll lose track of where the strings start and end. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: Hi parsifal, Right now i am working on source file of a software. It takes bytebuffer values from a function which i am trying to modify. So i would need to pass only bytebuffer as parameter. So i am thinking of passing it to array of bytebuffer values from an array of strings